# Range text is same after deselect in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, selection, contenteditable

I have a "mouseup" event handler inside a contenteditable to check wether text has been selected or not. If you highlight text after typing, all is good, but if you click again (to deselect text) the console shows that `range.toString()` is the same despite no text being selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/857876/

type something in the contenteditable, then select it, then click again (to deselect) and check the console. Both `console.logs` will be the same.

I need to differentiate between a real selection and a deselection. If this is normal behavior, how can I tell the two events apart, or how can I do it differently to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, Chrome does change the active selection **after** the mouseup event.

You could add an hackish timeout to this event, which might break some times...

Or you could use the Selection API's [selectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectionchange) event.

This event will fire every time the selection does change:

```js
$(document).on('selectionchange', function() {
  console.log(getSelection().toString());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="container">Select this dummy text</div>
```

Added benefit is that it will also work for keyboard selections.

And to get whether this event was a *selection* or an *unselection*, you can check if the content of the selection is empty, or if the current range is collapsed:

```js
$(document).on('selectionchange', function() {
  var isUnselect = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).collapsed;
  viewer.style.backgroundColor = isUnselect ? 'red' : 'green';
})
```

```css
#viewer{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer"></div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="container">Select this dummy text</div>
```

Comment: I marked as answered because you did answer it, but I was wondering if theres a way to do this but for contenteditable as well. "selectionchanged" only workes for textarea and input.

Comment: @bblocs3141 no, selectionchange works @ the document level, on any text. You are confusing with the `select` event, which indeed only fires on input and textareas.

Comment: oh, disregard my previous comment. Appologies. Noticed that in my own implementation (different than provded snippet) i had to make changes like you added in your example to correctly get this to work. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps.

```
$('#container').mouseup(function() {
  console.log(getSelectedText());
});

function getSelectedText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return '';
}
```